# Get contents of editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to develop a simple Eclipse plugin to understand how it works.

I have two questions about this:

How can I get the content of the active editor?

Do you have a good documentation about life cycle plugin and co? I can't find real good documentation on Google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding the content of the current editor, there are several ways to do this. The following code is not tested:

```
public String getCurrentEditorContent() {
    final IEditorPart activeEditor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
            .getActiveEditor();
    if (activeEditor == null)
        return null;
    final IDocument doc = (IDocument) activeEditor.getAdapter(IDocument.class);
    if (doc == null) return null;

    return doc.get();
}
```

Comment: @MartinVelez Not sure what you mean, but the code can be used in any view, dialog or handler to get the text of the current editor. So it can be added in many places.

Answer (score 11):

Tonny Madsen's answer is fine, but perhaps a little more transparent (getAdapter() is very opaque) is something like:

```
public String getCurrentEditorContent() {
    final IEditorPart editor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
        .getActiveEditor();
    if (!(editor instanceof ITextEditor)) return null;
    ITextEditor ite = (ITextEditor)editor;
    IDocument doc = ite.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(ite.getEditorInput());
    return doc.get();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're already familiar with using Eclipse as an IDE.

- Create a new plug-in project using the New Plug-in Project Wizard.
- On the Templates panel, choose "Plug-in with an editor"
- Read the generated code

If you're serious about writing Eclipse plug-ins, the book, "Eclipse Plug-ins" by Eric Clayberg and Dan Rubel is invaluable.  I couldn't make sense of the eclipse.org write-ups until after I read the book.