# How to get text from active editor in Eclipse PDE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a handler in which I would like to get the text from the active editor in my workbench.  From the screenshot below, I would like to get everything inside of Test.java ("public class Test...").

[image: Test class screenshot]

I've added a new command under the "Source" menu successfully.  Just not sure where to get the text from the active editor now.  Here's what I have so far in my attempt to get the text (it's just displaying the file name in a popup):

```
package generatebuilderproject.handlers;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;

public class GenerateBuilderHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    public GenerateBuilderHandler() {
    }

    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        IEditorPart editorPart = HandlerUtil.getActiveEditor(event);

        MessageDialog.openInformation(
                window.getShell(),
                "GenerateBuilderProject",
                editorPart.getEditorInput().getName());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse plugin: get content from editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661382/eclipse-plugin-get-content-from-editor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the `IEditorPart`, you can try the following:

```java
IEditorInput input = editorPart.getEditorInput();
if (input instanceof FileEditorInput) {
    IFile file = ((FileEditorInput) input).getFile();
    InputStream is = file.getContents();
    // TODO get contents from InputStream
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626959/get-the-current-source-code-of-an-eclipse-editor?rq=1)

```
IEditorPart editor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();

if (editor instanceof ITextEditor)
 {
   ITextEditor textEditor = (ITextEditor)editor;

   IDocumentProvider provider = textEditor.getDocumentProvider();

   IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();

   IDocument document = provider.getDocument(input);

   String text = document.get();

   ...
 }
```