# Get the current source code of an Eclipse editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I am working with Eclipse IDE. I want to develop a plug-in first of all, this plug-in allows me to get the whole source code as a simple string.

I made a simple "hello the world" plug-in using the template "hello world command". Now I am searching to get the source code from the editor of Eclipse and display it with System.out.println(); statement instead of showing HELLO THE WORLD.

I tried this but it shows me only the hierarchical sequence of my project, packageName/src/nameOfClass.

```
System.out.println(
    Workbench.getInstance().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput() 
);
```

My goal is to get the source code of the class itself (public class nameOfClass{ *** }).

Comment: thanks all of you
but i think , i'm having another problem with "IDocument", seems like my Eclipse is not importing it, or even know what it is
waiting for your answers :)
thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First do not use `Workbench` this is an **internal** class and must not be used. Use `PlatformUI` to get the workbench.

```
IEditorPart editor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();

if (editor instanceof ITextEditor)
 {
   ITextEditor textEditor = (ITextEditor)editor;

   IDocumentProvider provider = textEditor.getDocumentProvider();

   IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();

   IDocument document = provider.getDocument(input);

   String text = document.get();

   ...
 }
```

Note: Not all editors are text editors so this needs to be checked (the `ITextEditor` instance check above).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to adapt the IEditorPart into something that can give the contents? I don't have Eclipse SDK in front of me so I don't know what interfaces editors can typically adapt to, but I remember doing something like it in the past.

Comment: @E-Riz You can get the styled text control from the editor but this code is more general.

Comment: No, I was thinking of using `getAdapter()` on the `IEditorPart` to adapt it to something that directly returns the contents, EditorInput, or document. In general, Eclipse platform stuff encourages usage of Adaptable over instanceof and casts.

Comment: thanks all of you but i think , i'm having another problem with "IDocument", seems like my Eclipse is not importing it, or even know what it is 
waiting for your answers :) thanks again

Comment: `IDocument` is in the `org.eclipse.text` plugin, so you must add that to your plugin dependencies.

Comment: thanks a lot Mr greg-449
now everything is clear, there is no error, but i still can't achieve my goal, i tried with this code on two different plug-ins, but it is no use, nothing is shown
i'm so confused !!!

Comment: Do you get an active editor? Don't forget that when you test your plugin that Eclipse starts a new workspace so you need to open an editor in that workspace.

Comment: i integrated my plug-in into my eclipse, and i tried a simple exemple at the same workspace, but still get nothing

Comment: Be more specific, what don't you get? An active editor? Editor is not a text editor? ...

Comment: i added a simple line that prints the String text, but it is not working , in fact the whole block is not executed when i click on the  plug-in command, any other ways ?

Comment: thanks a lot Sir
do you have any channel on youtube ?
i wish to see some tutorials of you on youtube, it will be better for begginers like me :) to see step by step instead of reading answers

Comment: hi again sir
i think i found the main problem, "org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextEditor", the error is withing this line of code "ITextEditor textEditor = (ITextEditor)input;", any comments please ?