# IDocument cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm very new to eclipse plugin devalopment and i want to get content from editor using eclipse plugin so i found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6665993/2227526).

But problem is: I get the compile error `IDocument cannot be resolved to a type`. No quick fix imports available. My Eclipse version is  3.8.2.

How can I fix this problem?

The code I used (from the linked answer) is this:

```
public String getCurrentEditorContent() {
    final IEditorPart activeEditor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
            .getActiveEditor();
    if (activeEditor == null)
        return null;
    final IDocument doc = (IDocument) activeEditor.getAdapter(IDocument.class);
    if (doc == null) return null;

    return doc.get();
}
```

[image]

I can't find `org.eclipse.jface.text` among my dependencies. Here is a snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you add the `org.eclipse.jface.text` plugin to your dependencies, which `IDocument` is part of?

Comment: @user3567830 in my dependencies i canot find `jface.text`

Comment: So you mean the `org.eclipse.jface.text` plugin does not appear when you try to add it via the Dependencies tab in the `MANIFEST.MF`? If that's the case, your target platform is missing the plugin.

Comment: @user3567830 yes actually i haven't add dependencies.i thought it import automatically when need thanks .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IDocument` is in the `org.eclipse.text` plugin so you must add this to your plugin's dependencies list.

Note: You can also add the `org.eclipse.jface.text` plugin to the dependencies list as that will include the `org.eclipse.text` plugin.

Comment: one more question this worked for idocument.but i hav same problem for `ITextEditor` `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextEditor` but i can't add dependancies because when i type `org.eclipse.ui` `texteditor` doesn't popup but popup autocomplete worked for idocument .do i need to add download separately `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor` package ??

Comment: `ITextEditor` is in the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor` plugin so that needs to be in the plugin dependencies.